# How do I get this apple script to pop up a dialog?

Tags: applescript

The following apple script times out. How do I get it to work?

This runs from inside a bash script and it's supposed to pop up a dialog. It works fine on one mac. But it times out on my computer. However, it start to work after I run the script once inside Apple's Script Editor. Also, if I run the Script Editor version before the script timeout, the dialog pops up! Is this a permissions issue? What is going on and how do I fix it?

Bash Script:

```
osascript <<EOT
    tell app "System Events"
        text returned of (display dialog "Enter value:" default answer "default" buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with title "Type A Value")
    end tell
EOT
```

Error:

```
46:159: execution error: System Events got an error: AppleEvent timed out. (-1712)
```

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `display dialog` command is not a `System Events` command.  It is a `Standard Additions` command, therefore there is no need for a `tell block`

Also, inserting an `activate` command before the `display dialog` command will ensure the dialog window will appear on top of any currently opened programs or windows.

Try this...

```
osascript <<EOT
    activate
    text returned of (display dialog "Enter value:" default answer "default" buttons {"OK"} default button 1 with title "Type A Value")
EOT
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks!